# Adding row at the end of existing ones and create a delete button VBA Excel 2010

Tags: excel, button, excel-2010, delete-row, vba

Sorry for my poor English. I'm trying.

I want a script that allows me to add a row at the end of already existing ones and that also adds a button at the very beginning of this row so users can deleted it if needed.

I am copying the first row of the Worksheet because I have some formatting and equations i wished to keep.

This is the script that adds the new row :

```
Private Sub addRow_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Rows("1:1").Hidden = False
Rows("1:1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("LastRow").Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows("1:1").Hidden = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.Protect
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. Not sure if it is the best way to do it, but it is working in my case!

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If UCase(Target.Value) = "X" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift = xlUp
    End If

    ExitHere:
        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect
        Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
        Resume ExitHere


    End Sub
```